# Faster reporting where source is Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, bigdata

We have a Mysql Master Slave architecture. We have around 1000 tables. 5 or 6 tables in our db is around 30 to 40 GB each. We can not join one 30 GB table to another 30 GB table as it never returns result .

What we do : Select required data from one table and than find matching data in another table in chunks. This gives result to us, but this is slow.

After joining two tables in chunks we further process these tables. We use few more joins as well as per the use case.

Current DB: architecture: 5 Master Server, 100 Slave Servers.

**1. How can we make it faster ? Indexing is not an issue here, we are already using it.**

**2. Do we need some big data approach to get faster result.**

EDIT: Query Details Below

```
Query select count(*) from A, B where A.id = B.uid;
```

Table A 30 GB, have 51 Columns. Id is primary key which is auto incremental integer.

Table B 27 GB, have 48 Columns. uid (int 11) is non unique index.

MySql ISAM is used.

Comment: Just a note: using indexes and using them correctly are two different things. But without any actual information about structure, queries, plans etc it's impossible to answer.

Comment: ok i am editing my question

Comment: In particular, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: i will do that. but today i am at home. i don't have access to db. will do it tomorrow. Consider if queries are correct. Indexes are used correctly as well.

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be some suggestions on shrinking the datatypes -- smaller --> less I/O --> faster.

Comment: How much RAM?  Value of key_buffer_size?  About how many _rows_ in each table?

Comment: Please stop using `select ... from A, B` structure, it's bad practice. You should use a proper join instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's an awful query.  It will either

1. Scan all of A
2. For each id, lookup (randomly) the uid in B's index.

or

1. Scan all of B's index on uid
2. For each uid, lookup (randomly) the id in A (in the PK, hence i the data).

In either case,

- the 30GB of A will all be touched
- much of the uid index of B will be touched
- Step 1 will be a linear scan
- Step 2 will be random probe, presumably involving *lots* of I/O.

Please explain the *intent* if the query; maybe we can help you reformulate it to achieve the same or similar purpose.

Meanwhile, how much RAM do you have?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  And are the tables InnoDB?

The query will eventually return a result, unless some "timeout" kills it.

Is `id` an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Or is `uid` a "UUID"?  (UUIDs make performance worse, but there are some minor tips to help.)